# Android Flow-backed firestore realtime listener gets canceled on configuration change

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

## Project Structure

My goal is to build a real-time firebase (firestore) notes app (written in Kotlin).
The app just shows a list of notes and they are synced in real time with the server.

I'm using MVVM pattern and Firestore database.

The skeleton of the app contains:

- `NoteRepository` which connects to firebase and fetches the notes and listens for real-time document changes;
- `NotesFragmentViewModel` which exposes the notes (and the subsequent notes updates) to the views through a `Flow`;
- `NoteActivity` which is just a container (has no view model attached);
- `NoteFragment`, contained in `NoteActivity`, and observes its own ViewModel (`NotesFragmentViewModel`).

I'm not using `LiveData` anywhere, in favor of `Flow`.

Everything is working as of now, The app fetches the notes on startup and I get real time app UI updates when I make changes from the server.

## Code

#### Repository

```
class NoteRepository {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun notesFlow(): Flow<Result<List<Note>>> = callbackFlow {
        trySend(Result.Loading)

        val subscription = firebaseFirestore
                .collection("notes")
                .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                    // Real-time observer
                    if (error != null) {
                        trySend(Result.Error)
                    } else {
                        value?.let {
                            val data = it.toObjects(Note::class.java)
                            trySend(Result.Success(data))
                        }
                    }
                }
    
        // Suspends until the flow is not used anymore
        awaitClose {
            // Dismisses real time listener
            subscription.remove()
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class NotesFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repository: NoteRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _notes = repository
        .notesFlow()

    val notes: Flow<Result<List<Note>>>
        get() = _notes
            .onStart { emit(Result.Loading) }

}
```

#### Fragment

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NoteListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: NotesFragmentViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Consume data when fragment is started
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                // Since collect is a suspend function it needs to be called
                // from a coroutine scope
                viewModel.notes.collect {
                    when (it) {
                        Result.Loading -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        is Result.Success -> {
                            val data = it.data
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Got the notes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            
                            //
                            // Display the data on the UI
                            //
                        }
                        Result.Error -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Result

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()
    object Error : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

## Rotation (Configuration Changes) issue

The problem arises when the device rotates. (Or any configuration change is dispatched, which destroys the activity and the fragment)

After an orientation change, activity is recreated, fragment is recreated, and to my surprise **The documents are for some reason being fetched from the server again.**

Indeed, when I open the app I see a "Loading" toast, followed by "Got the notes!", then when I rotate the device I still get "Loading" and "Got the notes!". Just like the viewmodel also got destroyed and the app was killed and re-opened.

This (I suppose) is just deeply wrong and unacceptable, since it's the same behaviour I would have got without using MVVM / `Flow`. It's the main point, to keep your data safe and sound inside the ViewModel layer.

I expected the underlying `Flow` (Declared in the Repository layer, and exposed in the ViewModel) to be kept alive. Instead, I suppose that when nobody is "watching" it, it gets canceled and then re-created next time the fragment collects from it.

I'm trying to find a way to keep alive the real-time observer (the firebase snapshot listener) even after a rotation change. Or at least not to re-fetch all the documents after a rotation change and cache them somehow in the ViewModel.

I followed the repository [LiveDataWithFlow](https://github.com/fgiris/LiveDataWithFlowSample) as a base, as well as the articles [A Safer Way to Collect Flows](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda) and [Flows with Firestore](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-kotlin-flows-with-firestore-6c7ee9ae12f3).

###### Edit 1:

Maybe I should be using `LiveData` to glue ViewModel and the Fragment, or `StateFlow`, or something else. Is this approach appropriate?

###### Edit 2:

By connecting the ViewModel with the View with LiveData everything works as intended, rotation-proof. Still, I don't fully understand how you are supposed to handle a `Flow`-only scenario, and what are the advantages.

Comment: What I would change is that the fragment should observe (a LiveData or StateFlow) from the VM, and not do the Collect/Decision on whether it was success or not. Observe the stream in `onViewCreated` and let the ViewModel talk to the repo. Expose a better Sealed class for your UI that includes the list of notes (if you get a single shot list) and let the VM deal with the "result". This also gives you space to transform the results at will inside the VM. This doesn't explain the re-fetch though. We must be missing something, since it looks pretty straightforward. I haven't used flow much yet.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Can you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008654/what-is-the-correct-way-of-handling-collect-in-kotlin)?

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-effortlessly-get-real-time-updates-from-firestore-on-android-bcb823f45f20) will help.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is that you are calling all the actions from the lifecycle scope, which means that all the flow will be triggered on rotation changes since that is the lifecycle scope. To accomplish what you want and maintain the information even on rotation changes you have to make it dependant on the view model scope.

Here is an example of how that would look:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Coroutine that will be canceled when the ViewModel is 
               cleared.
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you can go to these couple of links to understand it better:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471